# How to retrieve N levels of many-to-many relations?

Tags: google-app-maker

I have this Data structure as this (with o/m = one to many relation):
Sites-o/m-Areas-o/m-Chapters-o/m-Sections-o/m-Topics and 5 other Data models Actions, Tools, Contacts... with a m/m relation to each 5 first models.
1 Site can have many Actions so as Areas...
Not sure if doable by Data binding, client or server script!
I wrote this server script solution but not sure if it's optimal as it's already slow with 2 levels!

```
function calculActions(kt) {
  var kn = app.models.Sites.getRecord(kt.toString());
  var knac = kn.Actions;
  kn.Areas.forEach(function(item){
    var knarac = item.Actions;
    if (knarac.length>0){
      knarac.forEach(function(ac){
        knac.push(ac);
      });
    }
    var knarch = item.Chapters;
    knarch.forEach(function(item){
      var knarchac = item.Actions;
      if (knarchac.length>0){
        knarchac.forEach(function(ac){
          knac.push(ac);
        });
      }
    });
  });
  return knac;
}
```

The goal is to displayed a tab for each asset (Actions, Tools, Notes...) associated to a same Site.
I'm sure there's a clean and efficient version of my draft!
Thx in advance for any help, I need to sleep :-)

Comment: As far as data bindings go for relations the standard datasource prefetch only allows you to go one relation deep. If you need to prefetch more than one relation deep than you want to explore the ‘Advanced’ option under the prefetch settings. This should speed up things significantly.

Comment: Thx Markus for your quick answer!
Because of my english, I'm not sure I understand the first part of it. You think I can handle this with Data binding only?
Or should I use advanced prefetch option and my script?
For the prefetch, I presume I have to use it only on the levels I need (Areas.Actions) no need for Areas? Could you confirm?
What about prefetch in code (prefetch.Areas._add())?

Comment: Since I’m not entirely certain about your setup it is hard to say what will or will not work. For one I’m not sure why you are using a server script to retrieve records, but it is certainly a good idea to include prefetch in server scripts also since it will speed things up. Using prefetch in your datasource settings and then implementing all your relations client side through bindings can work well also though and I implement this myself two relations deep like datasource.firstrelation.secondrelation in my own app. It really depends on what you’re trying to accomplish.